# How do I change the IP adress given for the shared connection?

Tags: network-manager, ip-address

I currently have my desktop PC dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu.  The PC has a wireless card installed.  I run a LAN cable from the PC to my Xbox 360.  In Windows 7, I can bridge the wireless and wired connections so that my Xbox gets an internet connection and its own IP address.  From my router, I can then open ports to my Xbox that it needs.

When I boot into Ubuntu, however, I run into issues.  I have the wired connection set to "Shared to other computers" under IPv4 settings as it should be.  The Xbox then has internet connection.  Instead of having a `192.x.x.x` IP address which I could open ports to, however, it is given a `10.x.x.x` address.  My router won't allow me to open ports to this address since it's on a separate subnet.

**Here's the question:**

How can I change the connection share so that it keeps my Xbox on the same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

**In graphical way u can try this link**

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

from command prompt try below

Hi you need to configure hostapd

I have configure following in hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf with WPA authentication options for wireless users

01 interface=wlan0

02 driver=nl80211

03 ssid=dontMessWithVincentValentine

04 hw_mode=g

05 channel=6

06 macaddr_acl=0

07 auth_algs=1

08 ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

09 wpa=3

10 wpa_passphrase=KeePGuessinG

11 wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

12 wpa_pairwise=TKIP

13 rsn_pairwise=CCMP

sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf